# "b.handleError is not a function" on image remove/upload

Tags: javascript, 6

I was not able to upload/remove CCK field images from the UI; when I looked at the console in Firebug, it said, "b.handleError is not a function." When I look for this error on Internet, I keep getting redirected to http://drupal.org/node/1064890, but this has a patch for Drupal 7.

Has anyone faced something similar?
More importantly, was this fixed?

I am using Drupal 6, and the following modules:

- jQuery UI 1.7.3
- jQuery Update 1.5.2

Comment: jQuery update for Drupal 6 will only get you as far as version 1.3.2. If you've got it using a later version then it's probably the dev release of the module in which case you should expect errors. Drupal 6 core has problems with v1.4 let alone v1.5

Comment: well as usual, there are modules that would only work with 1.5, so I did not have much of a choice.. I was hoping I could find something like a patch to jquery.form.js and resolve this..

Answer (score 0):

You can update the jquery.form.js as found in this comment:

https://drupal.org/comment/7520175#comment-7520175

I tried on my system which also makes use of a newer version of jQuery and it works like a charm.